# How to override readonly property in Swift subclass, make it read-write, and assign to superclass?

Tags: swift, properties, overriding, readonly, read-write

How can I override readonly property of a Swift superclass, from a subclass, to make the property read-write?

I want to do that, because that is what the iOS `UIResponder` documentation says is required. However, I'm getting an error when I try to implement what I think the Swift 5 documentation says can be done:

## Swift 5 documentation

### Inheritance

**Overriding Property Getters and Setters**:

> *You can present an inherited read-only property as a read-write property by providing both a getter and a setter in your subclass property override.*

---

## What Went Wrong:

Based on aforementioned Swift docs statement,  for which I found no accompanying example, I created the following subclass, at which XCode generates this error message:

"**Cannot assign to property: 'inputAccessoryViewController' is a get-only property**"

### My Subclass:

```
class InputAccessoryEnabledTextView : UITextView {
    override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
        get { super.inputAccessoryViewController }
        set { super.inputAccessoryViewController = newValue }
    }
}
```

## UIResponder

> ### Declaration
>
> var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? { get }
>
> ### Discussion
>
> This property is typically used to attach an accessory view controller to the system-supplied keyboard that is presented for UITextField and UITextView objects.
> The value of this read-only property is nil. If you want to attach custom controls to a system-supplied input view controller (such as the system keyboard) or to a custom input view (one you provide in the inputViewController property), redeclare this property as read-write in a UIResponder subclass. You can then use this property to manage a custom accessory view. When the receiver becomes the first responder, the responder infrastructure attaches the accessory view to the appropriate input view before displaying it.

*Note: I do see a question from 6 years ago on Stack Overflow that got no accepted answers and doesn't seem to properly answer the question, so please don't flag this as a dup without a good reason. Perhaps these questions can be merged later*

Comment: Is it really correct to call `super`? Shouldn’t you have your own object that this overriden property uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `super.inputAccessoryViewController` is not settable.

Your overridden implementation in the subclass, `self.inputAccessoryViewController` ***is***.

By adding a setter to the property in a subclass, you don't automatically also add the same thing in the superclass. What's in the subclass stays in the subclass.

So it's not that you can't override a property by adding a setter, you just can't set this here:

```
override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
    get { super.inputAccessoryViewController }
    set { super.inputAccessoryViewController = newValue }
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You can do other things, like:

```
override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
    get { super.inputAccessoryViewController }
    set { print("I just go set to \(newValue)") }
}
```

But that's not very useful. What you want is probably:

```
private var myInputAccessoryController: UIInputViewController?

override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
    get { myInputAccessoryController }
    set { myInputAccessoryController = newValue }
}
```

Comment: How does that help me? Why even override the property, then, if I can't pass it to super? Super is supposed to know what to do about it, and since it's a getter on the superclass, the implication is *something* can (and probably should) set it on the superclas so the superclass can show it with the keyboard.

Comment: @clearlight you can set it, and some other code could get the value that you’d set via the superclass.

Comment: IMO this auxiliary property should be set private

Comment: @Sweeper, ah, right... I see, so it's more like a protocol defined for the superclass, which is merely `UIResponder`, but it's managed and consumed by the inheriting class such as` UITextView` or `UITextField`. That makes sense. Thanks. I see an example of someone setting an inputAccessoryView via an extension to UITextField, which I was going to try, but I will try what you suggested now.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I have confirmed that in implementing your suggestion, the text subsystem is accessing the UITextView subclass such that, when the textView becomes first responder, the UIInputViewController I'm assigning to the overridden  inputAccesssoryViewController property is instantiated, which is the goal.