# Inheriting ugly: Swift subclass alters superclass' view of own stored properties?

Tags: swift, inheritance, properties, overriding, hierarchy

I have a subclass whose inheritance chain breaks down to look like this:

```
InputAccessoryEnabledTextField : UITextField : UIControl : UIView : UIResponder
```

**InputAccessoryEnabledTextField provides an override:**

```
private var myInputAccessoryController: UIInputViewController?

override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
    get { myInputAccessoryController }
    set { myInputAccessoryController = newValue }
}
```

The code above, working as the solution I was seeking, is from the  [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72578083/2079103) (@Sweeper) to a question I just asked on S.O. It is overriding an instance property of UIResponder.

However, it doesn't make sense to me. How *can/does* it work?

How is it possible that `UITextField`, superclass to my subclass, honors an override provided my subclass (`InputAccessoryEnabledTextField`)?

Doesn't that violate the inheritance hierarchy? Shouldn't only ***sub***classes of `InputAccessoryEnabledTextField` be able to see its override, not superclasses?

Or do overrides apply to the *whole object*, such that every inherited superclass sees the state of some arbitrary outermost subclass? Or, is it that the iOS text subsystem is doing some really convoluted stuff?

Maybe this is too abstract a question for S.O. and I don't mind closing or deleting it, Just posting this to avoid a 'dialog' in the comments that the bot complains about.

- Note: I don't find much clarity about it in Inheritence chapter of Swift 5 documentation *

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what you mean by this? "How is it possible that UITextField, superclass to my subclass, honors an override provided my subclass" What's surprising about it?

Comment: @Alexander that if it's allowed it seems to run against Swift's safety orientation insofar as I might violate assumptions made by opaque code without understanding why and introduce bugs that are nearly impossible to diagnose.  I guess in my mind, perhaps uninformed, the integrity of superclasses would be more sacrosanct and established completely within themselves.

Comment: @Alexander, was that a tacit confirmation that superclasses do utilize the overriden state of their subclasses? How do you or anyone know or assume that for Swift of CompSci in general? It may be obvious and I may be missing the obvious, but just checking.

Comment: This is a fundamental part of how class inheritance works, and is a major part of why Swift encourages us to avoid class inheritance. Yes, unconstrained inheritance can cause problems with invariants. Swift adopting a preference for struct+protocol is directly in response to this and related headaches. As you move from UIKit (which was designed for Objective-C) to SwiftUI (which was designed for Swift), you'll see the use of class inheritance drops off dramatically.

Comment: (But yes, the behavior you're seeing is expected, intentional, and heavily used. It just also creates various kinds of problems.)

Comment: @RobNapier, so appreciated. Can't thank you enough for that info/perspective.

Comment: @clearlight I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of classes and instances. "superclasses do utilize the overriden state of their subclasses?" Superclasses don't utilize anything. They're blue prints for instances. Subclasses are new blueprints that are based off their superclasses, but further refined. When an object is instantiated, it gets one set of methods, properties, etc. based off its class.

Comment: When a method on a class (at any level of the inheritance hierarchy) sends a message to `self` ("calls a method"), that message is resolved to a concrete implementation no differently than any other message sent. If an descendant class provides an override for that method, then it'll be implementation resolved for that message.

Comment: @Alexander I saw the possibility that it could be that the instance is the thing, wherein the outermost completes a single-point of truth reality to itself, and suppose it makes sense in some ways, but I'm glad RobNapier puts the pitfalls into perspective and the the problems that deterred my acceptance are real and taken seriously in Swift.  I guess in my years of object-oriented programming I never consciously did that or assumed it to work that way, so its just naive of me. But I won't be forgetting it. Thanks for explaining it.  Hole in my knowledge for sure. Pitfall of being autodidact

Comment: @clearlight One thing that would really cement your understanding is if you saw how message passing was implemented. It's most visible in Objective C, with `objc_msgSend`: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-20-objective-c-messaging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### *The following example code demonstrates that a Swift superclass experiences its own properties through *outermost* *subclass* overrides!*

(The example below proves @RobNapier correct, which I initially confirmed by successfully overriding `UIResponder.inputAccessoryViewController` and observing my viewController activated when the keyboard pops up for my subclassed `UITextView : UIResponder`)

**The Good:**

> Swift overrides as explained by @RobNaipier in comments, make sense, at least from certain points of view. And can obviously be exploited for its interesting flexibility

**The Bad:**

> However, it isn't what I assumed, and I was somewhat stunned that inheritance works that way, because intuitively I realized that letting subclasses tamper with superclasses` view of themselves is potentially risky, especially if one doesn't know superclass implementation details (as is the case with UIKits proprietary implementation code Apple doesn't release the source to the public).

**The Ugly:**

> So while Swift inheritance lets the inheritors achieve tweak things for interesting or useful effect, and could be very handy in some cases, in practical use, for example with UIKit, it does leads to anticipated problems and confusion.

The coup de grâce, which I'm grateful that Rob pointed out, is that, due to the anticipated downsides, class inheritance with UIKit is increasingly discouraged by Apple and struct+protocol has been adopted by SwiftUI.

```
class TheSuperclass {

    var x = 5

    init() {
        print("How superclass sees it before subclass  initialized: x = \(x)")
    }

    func howSuperclassSeesItselfAfterSubclassInit() {
        print("How superclass sees it after subclass   initialized: x = \(x)")
    }
}

class TheSubclass : TheSuperclass {

    override var x : Int {
        get { super.x + 10 }
        set { super.x = newValue }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("How subclass   sees it after superclass" + 
              "initialized: x = \(x), super.x = \(super.x)")
    }

}

TheSubclass().howSuperclassSeesItselfAfterSubclassInit()
```

The above code when run in Playground displays the following:

```
How superclass sees it before subclass  initialized: x = 5
How subclass   sees it after superclass initialized: x = 15, super.x = 5
How superclass sees it after subclass   initialized: x = 15
```

Comment: It's also interesting that the subclass can access the super's original stored property through super.x, but the superclass can't see its own original property even through self.x!

Answer (score 1):

## In short

This is indeed the overriding of properties. Swift deals with properties by generating code that is equivalent to accessing properties via a via getters and setters. This allows to override a property by overriding the getter and the setter.

## More explanations

### Your snippet is overriding of a property

In your code, `InputAccessoryEnabledTextField` indirectly inherits from [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder), which has an existing property [`inputAccessoryViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621124-inputaccessoryviewcontroller).

Your code snippet defines a new private property `myInputAccessoryController`, and uses it in the [overriding of the inherited property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html#ID196) `inputAccessoryViewController`, and more precisely, the overriding of its getter and setter.

### Purpose in the case of your snippet

In fact, the purpose of this overriding is even explained in the  documentation of [`inputAccessoryViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621124-inputaccessoryviewcontroller):

> The value of this read-only property is nil.

But what's the use of a property that is real only and returns only nil?

> If you want to attach custom controls to a system-supplied input view controller (such as the system keyboard) or to a custom input view (...), redeclare this property as read-write in a `UIResponder` subclass.

### How can property overriding even work?

While property overriding may seem weird at the first sight, we realize that this is just the normal [overriding mechanism](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html#ID196) once we have understood that:

> **The stored or computed nature of an inherited property isn’t known by a subclass—it only knows that the inherited property has a certain name and type**. You must always state both the name and the type of the property you are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your override matches a superclass property with the same name and type.

Here we see the power of Swift's properties. You can make any property public, and still benefit from encapsulation and specialization, overriding it like functions.  The explanation is that a property has two faces:

- the class-internal implementation details:  is the property stored or computed ?
- the implicit class interface for the external world, including for subclasses:  the outside world use the getter and the setter.  These can be overridden.
- the same principle works for property observers such as  `didSet`: you can override them even if the base class didn't define any special behavior for them.

Here a small unrelated but extreme toy example to illustrate this feature (I would not recommend its design ;-) ):

```
class Lense {
    init (opticalZoom: Int) {
        magnifyingFactor = opticalZoom
    }
    // stored property
    // And has implicitly a getter and a setter 
    var magnifyingFactor : Int = 2
}

class ElectronicLense : Lense {
    // overriden property
    // it overrides getter and setter, and uses the propery of the super-class to store the value
    override var magnifyingFactor: Int {
        get { super.magnifyingFactor * 5 }
        set { super.magnifyingFactor = newValue / 5 }
    }
    // pass through property
    var opticalFactor : Int {
        get {super.magnifyingFactor}
    }
}
    
var le = ElectronicLense(opticalZoom: 3)

print ("Zoom: \(le.magnifyingFactor) with an optical factor \(le.opticalFactor)")
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a good example of inheritance and overrides, but doesn't quite illustrate the specific form of it that I was confused about and see the pitfalls of. So I just created an example and posted it in the accepted answer, that shows how a subclass can change a superclass' self-perspective.